# Adding web URL as a source to media element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have been trying to set the source of media element to a web URL (pasted below) in WPF. But for some reason, i get a nell reference error on that thing. Whenever i try to play some local file in that everything is fine and good. If i try to set the exact same URL as a source for Windows Media Player in WinForms, that works fine as well. But it just doesn't work in WPF media elements.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            media.Source = new  Uri("https://d1m5sbyhb726tv.cloudfront.net/Ron%20Swanson,%20A%20Lifestyle%20(Vol.%20III)%20_%20Parks%20and%20Recreation.mp4");
        }
```

XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="New.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:New"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>

        <MediaElement x:Name="media"  Volume="1" LoadedBehavior="Play"></MediaElement>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Video URL : https://d1m5sbyhb726tv.cloudfront.net/Ron%20Swanson,%20A%20Lifestyle%20(Vol.%20III)%20_%20Parks%20and%20Recreation.mp4

Doesn't matter what example code, doesn't matter what to use (media element or something else)  i just somehow want to play a video in WPF using Web URL

I'm expecting to get some kinda example code or a solution to play web URL video on WPF.

Comment: Ran your exact code and it plays the video fine. Something else is going on. Where is the null reference exception throwing?

Comment: It doesn't really say anything, i just get these errors below in Locals list> Although the application runs fine but its just blank at the place of media element and a big tab opens up in my editor saying "Symbol Loading Skipped"

{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Variable value is not available because the module is optimized. Click the drop down for options.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your development environment. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how can i fix or check what issue it is?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're trying to debug while in release mode but that's just a guess. I suggest starting with an empty WPF project and rebuilding it bit by bit until the error returns (if it ever does).

Comment: even that doesn't work.